# How to view all ancestor processes?

Tags: grep, ps, filter

How can I view all the ancestors for all instances of a given process name?

Answer (score 2):

The `pstree` program seems to be quite nice for this e.g.

```
$ pidof bash | xargs -n 1 pstree -sp
init(1)───lightdm(1284)───lightdm(1577)───init(2017)───gnome-terminal(2595)───bash(18001)───man(10946)───pager(10955)
init(1)───lightdm(1284)───lightdm(1577)───init(2017)───gnome-terminal(2595)───bash(12895)
init(1)───sshd(1181)───sshd(11860)───sshd(11938)───bash(11939)───xargs(12124)───pstree(12127)
init(1)───sshd(1181)───sshd(9235)───sshd(9316)───bash(9317)
init(1)───lightdm(1284)───lightdm(1577)───init(2017)───gnome-terminal(2595)───bash(2897)
```

Comment: My version of `pstree`  (22.6) doesn't support `-s`; not sure what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Wildcard `-s` is the flag to show parent processes - so if your version doesn't have it, the approach won't work for you

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the following one-liner to accomplish this; there may be a better way.  The regex `/[b]ash/` is what selects the process name to match.

```
ps -ef | awk ' NR == 1 { header = $0; next } { pid[$2] = $0 } /[b]ash/ { toprint[$2] } END { print header; for (i in toprint) { while (i != 1) { split(pid[i], pieces, " "); i = pieces[3]; toprint[i] } } for (i in toprint) { print pid[i] } }'
```

I actually worked this out first as a full script and then condensed it to a one-liner; here is the more readable version:

```
ps -ef | awk '
NR == 1 {
  header = $0
  next
}
{
  pid[$2] = $0                    # Save all lines of ps -ef in this array, stored by PID
}
/[b]ash/ {                        # Modify this regex to change the filter
  toprint[$2]                     # Designate all these PIDs as "to print"
}
END {
  print header
  for (i in toprint) {            # For each PID designated "to be printed":
    while (i != 1) {
      split(pid[i], pieces, " ")  # Look up the info on that process
      i = pieces[3]               # Set i to the PPID
      toprint[i]                  # Designate that PPID as "to print"
    }                             # Recurse to get the parent of that process, until PID 1 is reached.
  }
  for (i in toprint) {            # Then actually print the data.
    print pid[i]
  }
}'
```

Example output:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root     23181 23137  0 15:33 pts/2    00:00:00 sudo su
vagrant  23136 23133  0 15:33 ?        00:00:01 sshd: vagrant@pts/2
root     23182 23181  0 15:33 pts/2    00:00:00 su
vagrant  23137 23136  0 15:33 pts/2    00:00:00 -bash
root      1041     1  0 Jan16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root     23183 23182  0 15:33 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
root     12980     1  0 10:58 ?        00:00:01 /bin/bash /var/cfengine/bin/runalerts.sh
root         1     0  0 Jan16 ?        00:00:01 /sbin/init
root     23133  1041  0 15:33 ?        00:00:00 sshd: vagrant [priv]
```

Note the parent PIDs listed in the above list.